# groupBy with collect_list of struct failure

Tags: java, apache-spark

This really looks like a bug, but I cannot find the reason nor any info on internet

What happens: I have some java code that restructure some input dataset using `collect_list(struct(...))` in the `agg` method following a `groupBy`. At first I had strange errors stating that `valueArraySize` which had some strange value should be positive (when the value was negative), or that it should be less then `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when it was way too big. What I understood is that spark read a long in an array of byte, probably a the wrong place, and got strange invalid number that make the code fail when using it.

To debug it, I tried to reproduce the bug with simple code. Here is a simple example that actually crash the jvm!

```
// Some definitions

@Data // use lombok to generate boilerplate code - no case class in java :\
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class Order {
    String user;
    String item;
    Double amount;
}

@Data
public static class Top {
    String user;
    List<Command> commands;
}

@Data
public static class Command {
    String item;
    Double amount;
}
```

And the code that fail:

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

    List<Order> orders = Arrays.asList(
            new Order("U1", "C1", 13.0),
            new Order("U1", "C2", 10.1),
            new Order("U2", "C3", 42.0));

    Dataset<Row> grouped = spark.createDataset(orders, Encoders.bean(Order.class))
            .groupBy("user")
            .agg(collect_list(struct( "item", "amount" )).as("commands"));

    List<Top> output = grouped.as(Encoders.bean(Top.class)).collectAsList();
```

Depending on the use case, I got different errors. For example, if all amount are integers (no decimal) or if I replace the type of amount by Integer, then the code works but the values of item and amount in the output are completely arbitrary.

Does anyone know about that bug/strange behavior?

I use this [spark version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.0.2.6.5.108-1)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0.2.6.5.108-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. I think what is causing the issue is described [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22708#issuecomment-429770726) inside the JIRA comments.

Should be fixed in version `2.3.3`

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way to make the code work while writing the question:

=> The list of column name in the `struct` need to be put in *alphabetical order*.

(So in the example above, `struct("amount", "item")`)

But I still don't know why. Can't find anything on the net. The doc of `struct` clearly mentioned that it output a schema with the column names. And it can be visualized in the schema So I would expect them to be used...